# compare two different DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, diff

i'm newbie in Pandas, please help.
I got two DataFrames to compare
DF1:

| Code | Product | Day | C_Code | Name | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Prod_X | 01.01.2022 | C_0001 | Mr_X | 12 |
| 002 | Prod_Y | 01.01.2022 | C_0001 | Mr_X | 24 |
| 001 | Prod_X | 15.01.2022 | C_0002 | Mr_X | 12 |
| 002 | Prod_Y | 16.01.2022 | C_0003 | Mr_X | 24 |
| 001 | Prod_X | 17.01.2022 | C_0004 | Mr_X | 12 |

DF2:

| Day | C_Code | Name | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2022 | C_0001 | Mr_X | 36 |
| 15.01.2022 | C_0002 | Mr_X | 12 |
| 16.01.2022 | C_0003 | Mr_X | 12 |

Column **Day** & Column **C_Code** unique.Conditions if DF1[**Day**]&[**C_Code**] == DF2 [**Day**]&[**C_Code**] then  compare **QTY**, if DF1.sum[**QTY**]<= DF2[**QTY**] write row into DF3, if  DF1[**QTY**] > DF2[**QTY**] then row from DF1 write into DF3 and put value from DF2[**QTY**], difference between DF1[**QTY**] and DF2[**QTY**] write into DF4. in the output should be

Correct List:

| Code | Product | Day | C_Code | Name | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Prod_X | 01.01.2022 | C_0001 | Mr_X | 12 |
| 002 | Prod_Y | 01.01.2022 | C_0001 | Mr_X | 24 |
| 001 | Prod_X | 15.01.2022 | C_0002 | Mr_X | 12 |
| 002 | Prod_Y | 16.01.2022 | C_0003 | Mr_X | **12** |

Incorrect List:

| Code | Product | Day | C_Code | Name | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 002 | Prod_Y | 16.01.2022 | C_0003 | Mr_X | **12** |
| 001 | Prod_X | 17.01.2022 | C_0004 | Mr_X | 12 |

How i understand i need to use groupBy, but i don't understand how
a lot of tnx for help!

Answer (score 0):

import pandas as pd
Did you try?

```
df = pd.merge(DF1, DF2, how='left', on='Day', indicator=True)
```

Comment: i need temporarily receive sum of column QTY in first df. (how i understood i need to do groupby ["day", "c_code"],agg("QTY").sum and merge first df with second. BUT, how to do it without loosing Code & Product & Qty of product in first Df?